# Why isn't Istio Passthrough example working as expected?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I tried passthrough example from https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-sni-passthrough/ but it seems it's not working.
I'm getting 404 with below logs: -

```
2020-01-29T17:21:12.551246Z info    accesslog.instance.istio-system {"apiClaims": "", "apiKey": "", "clientTraceId": "", "connection_security_policy": "unknown", "destinationApp": "", "destinationIp": "0.0.0.0", "destinationName": "unknown", "destinationNamespace": "default", "destinationOwner": "unknown", "destinationPrincipal": "", "destinationServiceHost": "nginx.foo.bar.us", "destinationWorkload": "unknown", "grpcMessage": "", "grpcStatus": "", "httpAuthority": "nginx.foo.bar.us", "latency": "146.827µs", "method": "GET", "permissiveResponseCode": "none", "permissiveResponsePolicyID": "none", "protocol": "http", "receivedBytes": 243, "referer": "", "reporter": "source", "requestId": "dd1b7b2b-10b1-9c36-ae64-cce9825773d2", "requestSize": 0, "requestedServerName": "", "responseCode": 404, "responseFlags": "NR", "responseSize": 0, "responseTimestamp": "2020-01-29T17:21:12.551334Z", "sentBytes": 60, "sourceApp": "istio-ingressgateway", "sourceIp": "100.108.31.87", "sourceName": "istio-ingressgateway-5b794cc7c9-82z4h", "sourceNamespace": "istio-system", "sourceOwner": "kubernetes://apis/apps/v1/namespaces/istio-system/deployments/istio-ingressgateway", "sourcePrincipal": "", "sourceWorkload": "istio-ingressgateway", "url": "/", "userAgent": "curl/7.64.1", "xForwardedFor": "192.
168.0.1,172.31.0.156"}
```

I've deployed Istio on Kubernetes 1.15.8 with following version: -

```
❯ istioctl version
client version: 1.4.0
control plane version: 1.4.0
data plane version: 1.4.0 (5 proxies)
```

Am I missing something?
Appreciate your help.

*Cheers,*

*-Ajit*

Comment: Hi, what infrastructure are you running Your cluster on? And You did everything like the example showed?

Comment: Created Kubernetes cluster with version 1.15.9 on AWS using Kops version 1.15.1.
And installed Istio with demo profile. Yes followed the guide as is but no luck :-(

Comment: Can You paste the command You are using to test connection? And verify if Your service serves content on `HTTPS` protocol. You have `"protocol": "http"` in Your response.